# inserting remote pdf into sql using openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a pdf file on a remote machine into a local sql server table.

The docTable has 2 columns. docName is varchar (50) and docContent is varbinary(max)

```
 insert into docTable(docName, docContent) 
 select 'sr123.pdf', '* from OPENROWSET(BULK '\\server01\e$\DocStore\InvoiceDocs\sr123.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB)'
```

This is giving an error

```
 Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

I am not sure if this is a single quote issue or a security issue while my local sql account is trying to access the remote file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 INSERT INTO docTable(docName, docContent) 
 SELECT 'sr123.pdf'
       , * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\server01\e$\DocStore\InvoiceDocs\sr123.pdf'
                           , SINGLE_BLOB)
```

You had extra single quote `'` wrapping your from clause.